# Login with BasicAuth React/Redux and Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, basic-authentication

Let there be a landing page that enables the *login*. This landing page has:

- Text field for user ID: LoginUserIDInput
- Text field for password: LoginPasswordInput
- Button to start the login process: LoginButton

React and Redux are supposed to do the following:

- If the credentials are entered in the dialogue and the "Login
  Execute" button is pressed  the authentication is carried out via
  basic authentication to the backend.
- If authentication is successful, the token is stored in the Redux
  store and redirected to the "private" page.
- If the "Logout" button    is pressed, the token in the Redux Store is
  deleted and redirected to    the start page.

The login process takes place via the http protocol. A separate BackEnd was created for the login process.

The login process is successful in that the basic auth is created from the credentials and a bearer token is sent back, but after the bearer token arrives I get an error message from the reducer.

**How can a successful login succeed?**

I will split the code into client and server side as I am not sure where the error is.

**CLIENT SIDE (REACT/REDUX)**

**AuthenticationAction.js**

```
    //here I transform the userID and the password into a hash
    //I get the Bearer Response. So the authentication process is 
    //succesful
    function login(userID, password) {
    const hash= Buffer.from(`${userID}:${password}`).toString('base64')
    const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {  'Authorization': `Basic ${hash}` },
    
    };
    console.log(requestOptions)
   

    
return fetch('https://localhost:443/login', requestOptions)
.then(handleResponse)
.then(userSession => {
return userSession;
});}

function handleResponse(response){

    //the problem starts here
    //if everything is ok, I want to dispatch a success message to the 
    //reducer, if not an error message


    const authorizationHeader = response.headers.get('Authorization');
    return response.text().then(text => {
        console.log('Receive result: '+authorizationHeader.split(" ")[1])
        const base64Credentials = authorizationHeader.split(' ')[1];
        const credentials = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    /* console.log(credentials.split(':')[3].split(",")[0]) */
    const [username, password] = credentials.split(':');
    console.log(username)
    console.log(password)

        const data= text && JSON.parse(text);
        
        var token = authorizationHeader.split(" ")[1]; 
        let userSession = {
            user: credentials.split(':')[3].split(",")[0],
            accessToken: token
        }
        
        return userSession;
    })}
```

**SERVER SIDE (express/node js)**

**AuthenticationRoute.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var authenticationService = require('./AuthenticationService')

router.post('/', authenticationService.basicAuth);

module.exports = router;
```

**Authentication Service**

```
function basicAuth(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.headers.authorization || req.headers.authorization.indexOf('Basic ') === -1) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            status: 'Fehler',
            error: 'Nicht autorisiert',
        });
    }
    const base64Credentials = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const credentials = Buffer.from(base64Credentials, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    const [username, password] = credentials.split(':');
    console.log("AuthenticationService " + username + " " + password);
    userService.getByUserId(username, function(error, user) {
        user.comparePassword(password.toString(), function(err, isMatch) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Fehler")
                throw err;
            }
            /*Passwort richtig*/
            if(isMatch) {
                console.log("Passwort richtig. Token wird erstellt.")
                var issueAt = new Date().getTime();
                var expirationTime = config.get('session.timeout')
                var expiresAt = issueAt + (expirationTime * 1000);
                var privateKey = config.get('session.tokenKey');
                let token = jwt.sign({
                    "user": user.userID
                }, privateKey, {
                    expiresIn: expiresAt,
                    algorithm: 'HS256'
                });
                console.log("Token erstellt: " + token);
                res.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                res.send("Token erfolgreich gesendet");
            }
            /*Passwort falsch*/
            else {
                console.log("Falsch.")
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: "Passwort und userID stimmen nicht überein."
                });
            }
        });
    })
}

module.exports = {
    
    basicAuth,
    
}
```

Comment: a 404 status code means not found. Now this could be how you are handling the body from your route(which you haven't yet shown). It can also be due to a request that is going to a route which is undefined.

Comment: The 404 ist not really the problem. I checked that, after I  posted my question. I specify the question a bit more.

Comment: "The code generated do not generate the basic auth" What do you mean by this ? Where is the problem coming from frontend/backend. Do you want us to go through all of your code which will take 3 days and figure out on which line is the problem. Don't just dump all of the code on us.

Comment: I will precise the question more.